# How to remove space between icon and surrounding div

Tags: html, css

I have a code as follows:

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left" style="font-size: 10rem;"></i>
  <div class="text">Title</div>
</div>
```

With next css:

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #f8f8f8;
}

.text{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}
```

Why my icon takes more space than it should take.
[image]

How can I remove it?

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/936Lx1gp/)

Comment: I think that's just the way it is with the font-awesome icons. I would set margin-bottom:-10px; to get around this problem

Comment: Have you considered using an svg image instead of an icon font?

Comment: @SwimmerF I can't. It needs to be an icon font.

Comment: try `margin-top:-1.25rem;`

Answer (score 0):

not the best way but you can use line-height

for example :

```
i{
    font-size: 10rem;
    line-height: 7rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```